# java how get all processes launched by jar

Tags: java, multithreading, browser, jar, process

In java I need to get processes launched by another jar.

A.jar -> B.jar ->some app(get Ids)

I have A.jar which launching B.jar, then B.jar launching some app (for example browser) I need get process id (PID) of this browser in A.jar and destroy this PID.

A.jar

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder builder;
        Process process = null;
        try{
            List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
            
                        command.add("java");
                        command.add("-jar");
                        command.add("B.jar");

                        builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);          
                        process = builder.start();

                        ProcessHandle processHandle = process.toHandle();
                        destroyProcess(processHandle);
                        //System.exit(0);
                    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
         }
..
..
private static void destroyProcess(ProcessHandle processHandle){
// destroy app of B.jar
}
```

B.jar

```
public class B{
public static void main(String[] args){
  // launch browser
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
}
```

Comment: This is more of an OS-dependent question - whether (and how) it is possible to get the processes started by another process. See https://superuser.com/questions/883081/how-to-find-out-who-what-process-is-starting-another-process and https://serverfault.com/questions/232762/linux-how-to-know-where-a-process-was-started-and-how-it-was-started - you would probably either have to call those commands or look for a library that does it for you.

Comment: Does `ProcessHandle#descendants()` / `#children()` not provide what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

thank you [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) found solution

```
processHandle.children().forEach(proc -> proc.children().forEach(child -> System.out.println("PID: [ " + child.pid() + " ], Cmd: [ " + child.info().command() + " ]")));
```

```
Stream<ProcessHandle> descendants = ProcessHandle.current().descendants();
                        descendants.filter(ProcessHandle::isAlive)
                          .forEach(ph -> destroychildproc(ph.pid()));
```

```
    private static void destroychildproc(long pid){
        String cmd = "taskkill /F /PID " + pid;
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
```